# C# System.IO.IOException

Tags: c#

I have following code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using VirusTotalNET;
using VirusTotalNET.Objects;
using System.Linq;
using System.Security.Permissions;

namespace VirusTotalNETClient
{
    class Program
    {
        private const string ScanUrl = "http://www.google.com/";

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            VirusTotal virusTotal = new VirusTotal("5d8684f50946c2bdeaf5c4fd966f61f3661de808e9d7324b99788d6f4fb7ad57");

            //Use HTTPS instead of HTTP
            virusTotal.UseTLS = true;

            //creating folder for programs reliqies and output log
            string folderName = "C:\\OnlineScanner";
            System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(folderName);

            //get list of files to analyse
            var paths = Traverse("C:\test");
            File.WriteAllLines("C:\\OnlineScanner\\test.txt", paths);

            foreach (string line in File.ReadLines("C:\\test.txt"))
            {
                //Define what file you want to analyse
                FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo(line);

                //Check if the file has been scanned before.
                FileReport fileReport = virusTotal.GetFileReport(fileInfo);

                bool hasFileBeenScannedBefore = fileReport.ResponseCode == ReportResponseCode.Present;

                //If the file has been scanned before, the results are embedded inside the report.
                if (hasFileBeenScannedBefore)
                {
                    int detekce = fileReport.Positives;

                    if (detekce >= 1)
                    {
                        using (var writer = new StreamWriter("C:\\OnlineScanner\\OnlineScannerLog.txt"))
                        {
                            writer.WriteLine(line);
                            writer.WriteLine("URL to test: " + fileReport.Permalink);
                            writer.WriteLine("Detect ratio: " + fileReport.Positives + "/54");
                            writer.WriteLine("Message: " + fileReport.VerboseMsg);
                            writer.WriteLine();
                            writer.WriteLine();
                        }
                    }
                    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(16000);
                }
                else
                {
                    ScanResult fileResult = virusTotal.ScanFile(fileInfo);
                    int detekce = fileReport.Positives;

                    if (detekce >= 1)
                    {
                        using (var writer = new StreamWriter("C:\\OnlineScanner\\OnlineScannerLog.txt"))
                        {
                            writer.WriteLine(line);
                            writer.WriteLine("URL to test: " + fileReport.Permalink);
                            writer.WriteLine("Detect ratio: " + fileReport.Positives + "/54");
                            writer.WriteLine("Message: " + fileReport.VerboseMsg);
                            writer.WriteLine();
                            writer.WriteLine();
                        }
                    }
                    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(16000);
                }
            }
        }

        private static IEnumerable<string> Traverse(string rootDirectory)
        {
            IEnumerable<string> files = Enumerable.Empty<string>();
            IEnumerable<string> directories = Enumerable.Empty<string>();
            try
            {
                // The test for UnauthorizedAccessException.
                var permission = new FileIOPermission(FileIOPermissionAccess.PathDiscovery, rootDirectory);
                permission.Demand();

                files = Directory.GetFiles(rootDirectory);
                directories = Directory.GetDirectories(rootDirectory);
            }
            catch
            {
                // Ignore folder (access denied).
                rootDirectory = null;
            }

            foreach (var file in files)
            {
                yield return file;
            }

            // Recursive call for SelectMany.
            var subdirectoryItems = directories.SelectMany(Traverse);
            foreach (var result in subdirectoryItems)
            {
                yield return result;
            }
        }

    }
}
```

This code run some time (arround 15secs) but then program crashs.

The error is

> System.IO.IOException, process can't access to file C:\hiberfil.sys.
>   http://upnisito.cz/images/2016_12/319crasherrror.png

Do you have any idea how to solve it?

Comment: Did you try giving the process access?

Comment: Yes, I run it under administrator access. It creates folder, then create a list to test on virustotal but then it crash after some time.

Comment: I think in this case the best course of action is to catch this particular exception, maybe log it, and move on. See this blog post: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2008/09/10/vexing-exceptions/  Particularly the section on exogenous exceptions.

Comment: Sounds to me it's trying to access the file and it's locked. C:\hiberfil.sys is a protected system file for the Hibernation state.

Comment: @AtomicFireball Agreed. I didn't notice the file name at first.

Comment: `var paths = Traverse("C:\test");` is going to be `c:` followed by `tab`, then `est`.  You're probably traversing your entire hard drive and hitting your hibernate file.  You need `\\\`.

Comment: Yes, but it's interesting because this code shouldn't do anything about that file...

Comment: Are you sure? What's the contents of that files?

Comment: @AlešWilk I'd suggest setting a breakpoint at File.WriteAllLines and analyze the paths variable to ensure it's only picking up what you're expecting.

Comment: First, the program gets file list in some directory, in my case it's C:\test. It's saved it C:\OnlineScanner\test.txt. Then it should go line by line and test every file on the list on virustotal.
Content of file is following:
`c:\test\blabla.txt
c:\test\dds.com
c:\test\EICAR.txt
c:\test\mapa.exe
c:\test\OnlineScanner.exe`
@AtomicFireball until that all works fine, the txt file is succesfully created.

Comment: Yes. I'm just wondering if C:\hiberfil.sys is included in your text file. I don't see anything in the code that would deviate from it, so I suspect it's got to be in the file somewhere. It might be just as @PaulAbbott said that you need to escape your strings with \\ on the \ character.

Comment: @AtomicFireball: yes, that's the point... I don't know why the crash is related to this... I tried \ also... nothing work.

Comment: Do you have a C:\test.txt file? Your foreach loop is looking for that file instead of C:\OnlineScanner\test.txt

Comment: @AtomicFireball: thank you! I am idiot... so this problem is fixed, but I have another one.. it look's like that string from line from text file isn't valid stream for FileReport fileReport = virusTotal.GetFileReport(fileInfo);..

Comment: I'm not familiar with the FileReport class. Perhaps you need to cast or convert the datatype?